# Validation failed for one or more entities - SaveChanges Section

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having this error when code goes to SaveChanges section.Here i'm going to validate textbox.

Model

```
 public class CustomerSupplierModels : DbContext
{
    public class Customer_Supplier
    {
        public int CustomerSupplierId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "FirstName is required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
     //Some code here
 }}
```

View

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)

        </td>
      //Some code here
}
```

Repository

```
public int AddorUpdateCustomerSupplier(Customer_Supplier cs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cs.CustomerSupplierId != 0)
            {
                context.Entry(cs).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Customer_Supplier.Add(cs);
            }

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}", validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                                  validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: FirstName is Required field.But when i'm going to validate.it shows the error

Comment: do you see any `firstName` value coming in?

Comment: Do you mean validation error does not display in your web page but you get to the repository save and it fails there? I'm not much familiar with ASP.Net MVC yet but it occurs to me that in your View you use a lambda with different names (`modelItem` and `item`) around the arrows `modelItem => item.FirstName`. Is it a typo in stack overflow or a problem in your code?

Comment: is that a list of suppliers you are passing to your view? if not put it outside for loop.. if yes, you have to take care of it in a different way..

Comment: in case of list, model binding to work properly you have to take some other approach.. go through http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx and http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: You should use EditorFor rather than displayfor. Else you can bind the textbox using Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) so that you can post textbox value to the model and then the validation will not throw exception that its required.

Comment: Why is your `return context.SaveChanges();` *outside* your try/catch?